# How can I add closed tag in xml document?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have next problem: I created downloader, which downloads xml documents, but in one the document has problem, in the document not end tag. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rows xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<row StateID="AK">
```

I have next code:

```
public void SaveFiles(SftpClient sftp, string DirectoryName, string PathToFile)
{
    foreach (Renci.SshNet.Sftp.SftpFile ftpfile in sftp.ListDirectory("." + DirectoryName))
    {
        DateTime downloadTime = ftpfile.LastWriteTime;
        string newFileName = ftpfile.Name;
        bool checkFile = check(PathToFile, newFileName, downloadTime);
        if (checkFile == true)
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(PathToFile + "\\" + ftpfile.Name, FileMode.Create);
            sftp.DownloadFile(ftpfile.FullName, fs);
            fs.Close();
            File.SetLastWriteTime(PathToFile + "\\" + ftpfile.Name, downloadTime); 

        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you showed the code that creates the XML. If you use the builtlin XML classes (`XmlDocument` or `XDocument`) things like that shouldn't happen. I say this assuming that you also create the XML. If some third party creates the XML, tell them they need to create valid XML.

Comment: Why is the document invalid to start with? Do you have any control over the source? It would be much better to fix the generation of the file than patch it up later.

Comment: I'd shout at whoever you're downloading the XML from.  You can't easily fix this as it's invalid XML and ambiguous how it should be fixed (how could you reliably tell where something like `rows` *should* end?)

Comment: I download  a document with FTPS and then his parse. when I parse then there is a problem because there are no closing tag

Comment: This document is not I create and I have no control over it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Document containing unclosed tag is not XML at all. As others suggested in comments, ideally the effort to fix this problem is done by the party that generate the document.

Regarding the original question, detecting unclosed tag in general isn't a trivial task. I would suggest to try [`HtmlAgilityPack`](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) (HAP). It has built in functionality to automatically close unclosed tags (closing tag added immediately after the opening tag).

**[example using HAP :](https://dotnetfiddle.net/P0yFeu)**

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;

......

var xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
<rows xmlns:fo=""http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"">
<row StateID=""AK"">";
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(xml);
Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml);
```

**output :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rows xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<row stateid="AK"></row></rows>
```